# how to pass today date as dynamic input date in power bi advanced editor?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to pass the day value as of today date in the advanced query editor

```
let 
    Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database(null),
    #"apple-5a221" = Source{[Name="apple-5a221"]}[Data],
    analytics_187358390_Schema = #"apple-5a221"{[Name="analytics_187358390",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    events_intraday_20200129_Table = analytics_187358390_Schema{[Name="events_intraday_20200129",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    events_intraday_20200129_Table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To pass Today dynamic date:**

After spending an hour I found a solution `[Name="events_intraday_`**`"&datetime&"`**" and declare the `datetime = DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(), "yyyyMMdd")`

```
let 
    datetime = DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(), "yyyyMMdd"),
    Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database(null),
    #"apple-5a221" = Source{[Name="apple-5a221"]}[Data],
    analytics_187358390_Schema = #"apple-5a221"{[Name="analytics_187358390",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    events_intraday_20200129_Table = analytics_187358390_Schema{[Name="events_intraday_"&datetime&"",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    events_intraday_20200129_Table
```

**To pass Yesterday dynamic date:**

datetime =  Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-1), "yyyyMMdd")

```
let
    datetime =  Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-1), "yyyyMMdd"),
    Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database(null),
    #"prutopia-5a221" = Source{[Name="apple-5a221"]}[Data],
    analytics_187358390_Schema = #"apple-5a221"{[Name="analytics_187358390",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    events_datetime_Table = analytics_187358390_Schema{[Name="events_"&datetime&"",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    events_datetime_Table
```